# Better way to generate unique random numbers in Java

Tags: java

I need unique random ints in specified range. I use this approch:

```
class Main
{
static final int RANGE = 100;

static int uniqueGenerator(int range_, boolean boolArr_[], Random rand_)
{
    int tmpVar = rand_.nextInt(range_);
    while (boolArr_[tmpVar] == true)
    {
        tmpVar = rand.nextInt(range_);
    }
    boolArr_[tmpVar] = true;
    return tmpVar;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();  
    boolean boolArr[] = new boolean[RANGE];
    Arrays.fill(boolArr, false);
    int ceiling = 10;
    int tmp = Main.uniqueGenerator(ceiling, boolArr, rand);
    System.out.println(tmp); => 5
    ceiling = 20;
tmp = Main.uniqueGenerator(ceiling, boolArr);
    System.out.println(tmp); => 17

}
}
```

It seems to be cumbersome. Maybe someone knows better approach?
EDIT: I use it in game code, so I need most efficient solution. Answers below suggest initializing new list, shuffling it => too resource consuming/need to generate new list every time when need to change range.

Comment: If you fill your boolean array with false, it will never enter the while loop, no?

Comment: What do you need? A unique integer in range 0-100?

Comment: Do you need unique within range or unique random within range?

Comment: @AdelBoutros, it does not need to enter the while loop for the first generation!

Comment: @Alf, but do you need ONLY unique or unique AND random? Because, if you need only unique, your life will be made very simple!
I am asking this because your question title mentions unique AND random, but in the description you mention only unique.

Comment: @GeorgeVremescu, yes, unique and random. Edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fill an array with the range of numbers you want, shuffle it and extract an item.

Edit: Look at [Eng.Fouad's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15310071/1864167) to see how this is implemented.

Comment: Won't get unique numbers + seems to concume too much resources at runtime. Need simpler/faster approach.

Comment: You will only have each number once, so you will only be able to get the same number once (provided you keep the pointer to the next item saved)

Answer (score 7):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) list.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Answer (score 3):

Generate and store random numbers in set

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(100);
    Random rand = new Random();
    while (set.size() < 1000) {
        set.add(rand.nextInt(100));
    }

    for (Integer integer : set) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
```